# How to use my CustomControl with javascript inside a gridview inside an update panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, .net-2.0

I got trouble when I want to add my custom control with an gridview and an updatePanel.
The javascript function is never added to the page even if I write it directly inside the RenderContent method.

The page is :

UpdatePanel
  GridView
    EditItem
      CustomControl

"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [APP_ROLE]">

The custom constrol looks like that :

[ToolboxData("<{0}:TestControl runat=server>")]
    public class TestControl : WebControl
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

```
        string script = "<SCRIPT type=\"text/javascript\">\n" +
            "function show_" + ClientID + "(){alert('toto');}" +
            "</SCRIPT>\n";

        if (Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("show_" + ClientID))
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "show_" + ClientID, script);
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("<a href=\"javascript:show_" + ClientID + "();\">click</a>");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your if statement is checking for the existence of the script block, then adding the script block *only if it already exists*.

I'd take out that if statement and see what happens.

Comment: Or add a ! in there somewhere.